# Quiero acceder al texto del textbox que esta dentro del DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, textbox

quiero acceder al texto del textbox que esta dentro del datatemplate pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Favor intenta no cargar imágenes en donde debería ir código, saludos.

Comment: Hay muchas maneras, algunas más correctas que otras, como tengo poco tiempo te dejaré una solución para salir del paso, NO es la correcta, simplemente ve al TextBlock y le agregas el evento Loaded y en el manejador, dentro de la clase, tomas el sender que es el mismo TextBlock y se lo asignas como valor a un atributo de clase de tipo TextBlock, de ese modo serán el mismo, luego puedes llamar a ese atributo y lo que hagas en él se copiará al control. Sé que es una solución horrible pero funciona.